# How to autosave HTML5 search input through javascript / without refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

**Question:**
Is there any way to trigger Webkit's autosave functionality from javascript? If not through a dedicated API, is there at least a way to accomplish the same functionality by manipulating cookies?

**Background:**
I really like the new "search" input type in HTML5 and want to give my Webkit-enabled users the benefit of easily recalling their past searches without the overhead of storing all those searches in my database (using the autosave functionality).

The problem I'm hitting is that the search terms seem to only get saved if the search input is encapsulated in a form and that form executes a standard POST on submit. Since my search input is being used to filter results that are already present it doesn't make much logical sense to completely reload the page, so I'm using AJAX to repopulate the results. The interface is all clean and consistent if I return false in my AJAX function, but this obviously doesn't trigger the form POST [by design] so the browser (at least Chrome) doesn't save the search term. Returning true refreshes the entire page, destroying my AJAX-injected content and the entire point of the filter, but the search term is saved.

```js
$('#filter-form').submit(function(e) {
      var term = $('#filter').val();
      $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/GetResults',
        data: {
          filter: term
        },
        success: function(returnData) {
          $('#result-list').html(returnData);
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
```

```html
<form id="filter-form" name="filter-form" action="#">
  <input type="search" name="filter" id="filter" results="5" autosave="EluminitePreviousFilters" />
</form>
<div id="result-list"></div>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Would saving your own list in localStorage be an option? You can keep a list and push to it on submit and save the `JSON.stringify(list)` to localStorage.

Comment: @JimBolla OP has more than two years and *Eluminite* is not connected since February this year ... You have exactly the same problem? I would recommend you to open your own question specifying your setting, problem and what you've tried to get it.

Comment: @JimBolla Tried jQuery UI autocomplete remote with cache https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache ?

Comment: Have you tried called `e.preventDefault();` instead of returning false? That will prevent the form submit, and maybe it would be enough to trigger the "autosave" functionality in WebKit?

Comment: @BillCriswell Made a good point with using `localStorage` (or `sessionStorage`, depending on your purposes)

Answer (score 8):

There is a trick that uses a hidden iframe connected to the form:

```
<iframe id="hidden-frame" name="hidden-frame" style="display:none" src="about:blank"></iframe>

<form target="hidden-frame" method="post" action="about:blank">
  <input type="search" name="filter" id="filter" results="5" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If your form submit handler returns true, form will be submitted (but users won't notice), and the browser will save the entered value in the autocomplete list.

I've created an example on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/farelufaku/edit?html,output

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but I already figured the solution will be. Unless there's some blessed API for accessing the autosaves, this will earn the bounty.

Comment: I wish there was an API for this (or I knew about an existing one).

Answer (score 1):

> **demo:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/how-to-autosave-html5-search-input-through-javascript-without-refresh/

Hi Eluminite, i know this maybe out of question(?) but since you say:

> *at least a way to accomplish the same functionality by manipulating
>   cookies?*

and if i'm not wrong your main goal is to not store data in database; you can actually use

> [The Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) that provides mechanisms by which browsers can store key/value pairs, in a much more intuitive fashion than using cookies.

as you see it is supported by a various number of modern browsers and where it doesen't support it you can still use cookies...

see my demo for a code implementation using jQuery UI autocomplete.

> **NOTE:** there are of course plugins out there that can **handle** both **Local Storage** and **cookies** **at the same time** like these [jQuery-Storage-API](https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API), [jQuery Storage](http://yckart.github.io/jquery.storage.js/) and many other. just search google.

hope this help.